# App crashing with no error message from imported function typescript

Tags: typescript, express, mysql2

When I import a helper function called `insertStudent` in my controller for authorization and register the route with the controller the app crashes with no error message. The controller function (`signup`) isn't even being run. Also when I try out the helper function without the controller but just by itself it seems to work perfectly fine. What could be causing the crash?
Here's the code:

Imported helper function in `database.ts`:

```
export const insertStudent = async (
    firstName: string,
    middleName: string,
    lastName: string,
    email: string,
    password: string,
    numberInGrade: number,
    gradeId: number
): Promise<Student> => {
    const [rows] = await db.query(
        "INSERT INTO students (first_name, middle_name, last_name, email, password, number_in_grade, grade_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?); SELECT * FROM students WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID();",
        [
            firstName,
            middleName,
            lastName,
            email,
            password,
            numberInGrade,
            gradeId,
        ]
    );

    return rows[1][0] as unknown as Student;
};
```

Controller function `signup` for the autorization:

```
import {
    insertStudent
} from "../database.js";

export async function signup(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const { userType, firstName, middleName, lastName, email, password } =
        req.body;

    if (
        !userType ||
        !firstName ||
        !middleName ||
        !lastName ||
        !email ||
        !password
    )
        return res.status(400).send({ message: "Please fullfil all fields." });

    if (userType === "student") {
        const { numberInGrade, gradeId } = req.body;

        if (!numberInGrade || !gradeId)
            return res
                .status(400)
                .send({ message: "Please fullfil all fields." });

        const hashedPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(password);

        try {
            const user = await insertStudent(
                firstName,
                middleName,
                lastName,
                email,
                hashedPassword,
                numberInGrade,
                gradeId
            );

            delete user.password;

            return res
                .status(201)
                .send({ message: "Student created successfully", user });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("error: ", error);
            return res.status(400).send({ message: "Error creating student" });
        }
    }

    return res.status(400).send({ message: "Invalid user type" });
}
```

File where the router is located (`auth.ts`):

```
import { Router } from "express";

import { signup } from "../controllers/auth.js";

export const router: Router = Router();

router.post("/signup", signup);

export const path = "/auth";
```

I use the exported `path` and `router` from `auth.ts` to register the routes using `app.use(path, router);` in my main file.

I usually use `nodemon` to run the code but when I compile the code from `TypeScript` to `JavaScript` I get an error which says the following:

```
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".map" for [PATH REDACTED]\build\routes\auth.js.map
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:377:5)
    at Object.getFileProtocolModuleFormat [as file:] (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:80:11)
    at defaultGetFormat (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:122:38)
    at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:21:20)
    at ESMLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:431:26)
    at ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:350:22)
    at new ModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:66:26)
    at #createModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:369:17)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:328:34)
    at async Promise.all (index 0) {
  code: 'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION'
}
```

After that I just get the message that server has started:
`Server started on port 8393`

Here's my `package.json`:

```json
{
    "name": "server",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node build/index.js",
        "dev": "nodemon --exec ts-node-esm src/index.ts",
        "devdb": "nodemon --exec ts-node-esm src/database.ts",
        "build": "npm run clean && tsc && cp src/.env build/.env",
        "clean": "rm -rf build",
        "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "MIT",
    "dependencies": {
        "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "dayjs": "^1.11.7",
        "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
        "express": "^4.18.2",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
        "mysql2": "^2.3.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.2",
        "@types/cors": "^2.8.13",
        "@types/express": "^4.17.15",
        "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.1",
        "@types/mysql2": "github:types/mysql2",
        "@types/node": "^18.11.18",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.47.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.47.1",
        "eslint": "^8.30.0",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
        "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
        "typescript": "^4.9.4"
    }
}
```

Exact output from `nodemon`:

```
$ npm run dev
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

> server@1.0.0 dev
> nodemon --exec ts-node-esm src/index.ts

[nodemon] 2.0.20
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: ts,json
[nodemon] starting `ts-node-esm src/index.ts`
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: that looks like you're using a js file in a ts file?. line 3 in auth.ts, importing auth.js?

Comment: @SohailHaqyar I don't think that's an issue since it's just because when it's turned into js it needs to import a js file.

Comment: you can't interlop js and ts files. The ts just won't compile

Comment: @SohailHaqyar I'm not doing that. The database.js from which I'm importing is actually a ts file but my config automatically makes me use js because when I compile it'll cause errors otherwise.

Comment: have you tried using ts-node to run the typescript, it may give you more info regarding what's gone wrong. you can do: `npx ts-node your_ts_file.ts`

Comment: @SohailHaqyar When I run this I get this error no matter what file I use (even if it's just a `console.log("hello");`):
`TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for [FILE]`

Comment: Can you describe the crash? Does it hang or does it exit? Don't worry about the other commenters suggesting you need '.ts'. '.js' is correct if you have evertything confgured to run as ESM.

Comment: @Evert What does it mean to either hang or exit because I'm not sure.

Comment: You said 'the app crashes'. Can you describe what that means to you? I've noticed before that people here have very different definitions of crash so you can just elaborate what actually happens when it 'crashes'

Comment: @Evert By crash I mean that in this case I don't get a stack trace (no errors in the logs) but it just says the app crashed when running it with `nodemon` or it just exits when I run the compiled `js`. I'm going to upload the `package.json` because the error might be in the npm scripts.

Comment: @ProGamer2711 edit your question and share exactly the output you are getting from nodemon when this happens.

Comment: This question is a bit confusing you've said that you're using typescript but all the code snippets are in javascript and they even import .js files. Anyway, I have a quesiton for you, why are you using "ts-node-esm" instead of "ts-node", any specific reason? Did you try the following command? "nodemon --exec ts-node -T src/index.ts"

Comment: @LucasA The problem is not in that. Don't worry about it. The `sourceMap` option in `tsconfig.json` I now have enabled but the error still occurs.